# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html5-canvas

i am new to angular 2 and i work on image cropping plugin and i want to display the image on canvas.
here my html code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
     <canvas id="layout" width="400" height="300">
        This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
     </canvas>
```

and here is my typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-four',
templateUrl: './four.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./four.component.css']
})
export class FourComponent implements OnInit {
image: HTMLImageElement;
profPic: any;
context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

constructor() { }
@ViewChild('layout') canvas;
@ViewChild('photo') photo;

ngOnInit() {
const _canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;
//let photo = this.photo.nativeElement;
this.context = (<HTMLCanvasElement>_canvas).getContext('2d');
  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.src = '../../assets/images/1.jpg';

this.context.drawImage(this.image,20,20,500,260);

}
}
```

and i have error

***ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined***

please help me to fix this

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `layout` local template variable

```
 <canvas #layout id="layout" width="400" height="300">
        This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
     </canvas>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3u5phr?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: sir error is fixed. strokeRect also work but my image is not shown there

Comment: Check the path of the image

Comment: _this.context.drawImage(this.image,20,20,500,260);_ is there any problem with this one

Comment: No problem you can check the demo app

Comment: sir every thing  is fine with your src google  image but my image src path is not correct sir i still work on it. my images in assets/images folder but still it is not working

Comment: in demo i have to refresh 2 time to get image why is it happen

Comment: check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3u5phr?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

With the update to Angular 8 the ViewChild changed slightly, you can get taste how it does works from the following code snippet:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="showMe" #viewMe>Am I here?</div>
    <button (click)="showMe = !showMe"></button>
  ` 
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  @ViewChild('viewMe', { static: false })
  viewMe?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>; 

  showMe = false;
}
```

With a Renderer2 (without accessing DOM directly) it would go as follows:

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer2) {}

@ViewChild('one') d1:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const d2 = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  const text = this.renderer.createText('two');
  this.renderer.appendChild(d2, text);
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.d1.nativeElement, d2);
}
```